# Git subtree on root

Tags: git, github, branch, git-subtree

I have 3 repositories:

1. core
2. module1
3. module2

And I want to do the following structure on a 4th repository:

- core: on the root as a git subtree on master (which includes an
  angular app, with some folders and "app/modules" directory
- on: ./app/modules/ => the module1 repo

So with this structure I can create some other projects, reusing a "core" structure.

I'm not having success with the git subtree add command.
Any clues?

Comment: `git submodule`s maybe? What is your actual question? what is not working?

What do you mean by
> So with this structure I can create some other projects, reusing a "core" structure.
?

Comment: I want to have the "core" code in the root of the other project (if possible) with submodule I cannot do that

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, that is exactly what a `submodule` would do and is for. Where you have your core repo and at /app/modules is the submodule